# Sending automated SMS messages from an app

Tags: ios, sms

I'm not a developer, just looking for advise as to whether something is possible.

I'm working with a team who are developing an application that will contact a persons emergency contact on a specific trigger. Is it possible for a app to send an SMS message without user intervention to a persons emergency contact? I can find discussion about this saying it isn't possible, but only for very old versions of iOS.

Thanks

Comment: No, you cannot send SMS' on the user's behalf.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation, you need to send SMS from the backend. There are a lot of different services for this but what comes to my mind now is Twilio.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at that. Given that we will be using data services I'm also looking at AWS SNS. I think if we're using data then keeping the packets small is key so it can work over the edge network if needed